# Getting Hyper-V-Hypervisor launch failed - I have windows home

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I am running windows 10 home.

disabled hyper-v from my services.

[image]

have virtualization disabled from bios

do not have it in my start up either.

On boot up I keep getting these 4 errors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you need anything else to help with this issue. I feel something else is trying to start hyper-v but I only have 1 startup application and its my mouse software I disabled everything else trying to find the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

[image]

Comment: You cannot install Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home.  If it’s installed then your not running Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Yes I am aware which is why I'm confused on how I am getting those errors. I have it all disabled and everything but it seems on boot up it is trying to launch. I am looking for the cause of why it is trying to launch

Comment: The hypervisor is not a service. It starts even before Windows does. Do you have WSL 2 enabled?

Comment: My WSL is disabled when I check under windows features.

Comment: @schylake - It appears you are mistaken about having Windows 10 Home based on those events, Windows is expecting hardware virtualization to be enabled, hence the reason it's recording those errors.  So what software do you have installed that requires hardware virtualization to be enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound updated with a screen shot of my windows specifications. On a side note I installed Docker when I realized I need an upgraded Windows edition to get it working. I uninstalled it and maybe some of the settings did not change back? I had to manually change things back.

Comment: ' I had to manually change things back." - You made no mention of this in your question.

Comment: Do you have any of the following Windows Features activated: "Virtual Machine Platform", "Windows Hypervisor Platform"?

Comment: @Ramhound I was researching as I posted this and it is what I learned. you make it sound like a bad thing. You seem to be upset and that was not my intention

Comment: @Daniel B both seem to be disabled as well when i go to my windows features.